# Using tensorflow tf.nn.conv2d with float64 input and output

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to run physics simulations using tensorflow. I have found that tf.nn.conv2d only takes float32 input. My understanding for this is that for machine learning application using float64 does not lead to improvements of any type and because GPU normally uses float32. Is there a way to hack tf.nn.conv2d to make it use float64 even if I have to run the model on CPU only? Or is there an alternative to tf.nn.conv2d that I can use with float64